# Reach out to ModelMetadata of one of model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelmetadata, asp.net-mvc-templates

I was reading one of Brad Wilson's articles:

> **ASP.NET MVC 2 Templates, Part 2: ModelMetadata**
>
> http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html

Let's assume that on my ASP.NET MVC 3 App, I have the following model:

```
public class Contact {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Contact

<h2>Contact</h2>

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and I have a `Contact.cshtml` file inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` path.

My question is how I can reach out to `ModelMetadata` of each model property. For example, like following:

**Contact.cshtml**

```
@model MyApp.Models.Contact

<input type="text" placeholder="@Model.FirstName.GetItsMetaData().Watermark" 
       value="@Model.FirstName" />
```

> **NOTE:** GetItsMetaData method is something which I totally made up. I am just trying to get to MedelMetadata of the property. Doesn't have
>   to be that way.

**EDIT**

I found another similar question:

[ModelMetadata for complex type in editortemplate in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336920/modelmetadata-for-complex-type-in-editortemplate-in-asp-net-mvc)

and the answer is this:

```
@{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata
        .FromLambdaExpression<TestThing, string>(x => x.Test2, ViewData);
    var watermak = metadata.Watermark;
}
```

But it is quite verbose to do this for every single property of my model, isn't it?

Comment: Hi tugberk, I just wanted to answer to your question "*Performance difference between Entry<TEntity>(entity) and Entry(entity) on Entity Framework 4.2*" but at the same moment you deleted your question, lol. Point is: *The compiler* will select the generic overload when you call `Entry(entity)` (generic type inference). The same method is called no matter if you specify the generic parameter or not. (The only exception is if `entity` is of type `object` *at compile time*, then the non-generic overload is called.) Because the compiler calls the same method there is no performance difference.

Comment: @Slauma yeah, they think the question was stupid and I didn't wanna get into an argument so I deleted it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is less verbose to create an HtmlHelper to use for this purpose.  The helper would look like this:

```
    public static string WatermarkFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        return metadata.Watermark;
    }
```

You would use it as follows in your example:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Contact  

<input type="text" placeholder="@Html.WatermarkFor(x => x.FirstName)"   
    value="@Model.FirstName" />
```

Comment: nice way! still requires a lot of work. This `FromLambdaExpression` method uses reflection behind the scenes, right?

Comment: If it's too much work, then use this one instead: @Html.MagicallyGetWatermark() :)

Comment: @Dismissile cannot say that it tickles me.

Comment: Whenever you are accessing a property's metadata, some reflection is involved.  However, the actual costs of using reflection under these circumstances are very small.